# Exponential or not ? Evaluating an answer.

Tags: exponential-function

So I have a question involving definition of exponential function. Regarding the Arrhenius equation in Chemistry where $$ k = Ae^{-\frac{E_a}{RT}} $$

​
and the variables are the rate constant k and the temperature T (in Kelvin). Is it correct to say that "the rate constant, k, for a reaction increases exponentially with increasing temperature"?

Comment: No. The argument of the exponential is the reciprocal of temperature. So even though it is true that $k$ increases with $T$, it does not do so exponentially (in the strict sense of the word).

Comment: Indeed, as the temperature increases without bound, the rate constant stabilizes, getting closer and closer to $A$—definitely different from exponential increase.